# RVM can't switch to Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed Ruby 1.8.7 through apt-get. I then installed 1.9.1 through RVM.

The RVM 1.9.1 installation was successful:

```
root: rvm install 1.9.1
<i>Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378 </i>
<i>/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p378 has already been extracted. </i>
<i>Configuring ruby-1.9.1-p378, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)... </i>
<i>Compiling ruby-1.9.1-p378, this may take a while, depending on your cpu(s)... </i>
<i>Installing ruby-1.9.1-p378 </i>
<i>Installation of ruby-1.9.1-p378 is complete. </i>
<i>Updating rubygems for /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378@global </i>
<i>Updating rubygems for /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378 </i>
<i>adjusting shebangs for ruby-1.9.1-p378 (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake). </i>
<i>Installing gems for ruby-1.9.1-p378 (rdoc rake). </i>
<i>Installing rdoc to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378@global </i>
<i>Installing rdoc to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378 </i>
<i>Installing rake to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378@global </i>
<i>Installing rake to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378 </i>
<i>Installation of gems for ruby-1.9.1-p378 is complete. </i>
```

However, I cannot get RVM to switch to the new version:

```
root: ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]

root: rvm 1.9.1

root: ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
```

Despite that, it seems to have installed fine:

```
root: /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.1-p378 -v
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [x86_64-linux]
```

I also tried setting the **rvm --default** to 1.9.1 but that did not help.

Why can't RVM switch to the new version? Should I just set an alias for ruby=1.9.1?

*running Debian

Comment: Check your /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin/ directory for the 'ruby' binary. Is it a symbolic link to ruby1.8.7? If so change it to 1.9.1

Comment: This is somewhat a typical problem with root installs. It's better to stick to local user install so do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hop on #rvm irc.freenode.net and ask RVM's creator for help, wayneseguin.  He's a super guy and he'll sort out your issue in no time. http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm

Answer (score 1):

http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm   << Go There. Ask for Wayne.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, switched to ruby 1.9.2, that works. So if you don't have a compelling reason to use 1.9.1 then I'd recommend

> rvm install 1.9.2